# How should one initialise this member vector in C++11-style?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, initialization

I have a class with a member variable which is a `std::vector<double>`. I would like to initialise this in the initialisation list of the class. I've tried the following code

```
MyClass::MyClass()
  : m_myMemberVector( { 1.0, 2.0 } )
{...}
```

but the compiler interprets this as the `(itBegin, itEnd)` constructor for `std::vector`. I've seen this question [error: ‘double’ is not a class, struct, or union type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16886865/error-double-is-not-a-class-struct-or-union-type), which points out the input iterator issue but doesn't provide a solution.

I have a working implementation using BOOST in the body of the constructor, but I'd rather do this in the initialisation list if possible. Is there any elegant way to construct a vector containing two doubles using C++11-style initialisation?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: Are you sure that constructor gets chosen? Can you post code to prove it? In any case, try omitting the `()`, i.e `m_myMemberVector{ 1.0, 2.0 }`.

Comment: Remove the braces `m_myMemberVector{ 1.0, 2.0 }`

Comment: Wait: did you enable C++11? And still getting the iterator error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::initializer_list<double>{ 1.0, 2.0 }` instead of `{ 1.0, 2.0 }` might work, as might removing the `()` around `{ 1.0, 2.0 }`.

Odds are this is a bug in your compiler, so making things more explicit may help.

Another possibility is that `m_myMemberVector` is not a `std::vector<double>` actually, or that your standard library you are using is not C++11 enabled.

Answer (score 2):

The simple solution was correct: C++11 wasn't properly enabled. I saw compiler output of the form

```
MyClass.cxx:5:5: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
```

and assumed this meant that C++11 support would be "enabled by default"! Recompiling with the explicit use of `-std=c++11` worked as expected.

There was an answer suggesting this, which I wanted to accept, but it seems to have been deleted. Thanks for all the comments which made this point.

Comment: FYI, you don't have to accept the other answer as you have currently done. You can for example accept this, your own, answer after a certain timeout.

Comment: also, the ``[enabled by default]`` refers to the warning. other warnings show as ``[-Wfoobar]``. And always compile with ``-Wall -Wextra -Werror`` (or at least ``-Werror``), if you’re writing new code (and thus can adhere to certain quality standards), that avoids lots of mistakes.

Comment: Thanks Jonas Wielicki. I guess this was a bit of PEBKAC in interpreting the compiler output! I actually normally compile with those flags in my own projects but in this case I don't have control over the Makefile.