# error: ‘int’ is not a class, struct, or union type`

Tags: c++, stl, compiler-errors

I am getting error for my code.

```
vector<vector <int> > v;
deque <TreeNode, int> q;
pair <TreeNode, int> temp;//, node;
temp.first=*root, temp.second=0;
q.push_back(temp);   // error is in this line
```

TreeNode is a structure defined as:

```
struct TreeNode {
    int val;
    TreeNode *left, *right;
    TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
};
```

The error I am getting on compiling the code is: `/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_deque.h:487:61: error: ‘int’ is not a class, struct, or union type`

I am still unclear after following [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16886865/error-double-is-not-a-class-struct-or-union-type) posts on stackoverflow. Can someone please explain what could be the reason?

Comment: You cannot use `int` as the second template parameter of `deque`. That has to be an allocator. Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: Maybe you meant `deque< pair<TreeNode, int> >`

Comment: I am trying to store a structure and integer in a queue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
vector<vector <int> > v;
deque <pair<TreeNode, int> > q; // here is the different
pair <TreeNode, int> temp;//, node;
temp.first=*root, temp.second=0;
q.push_back(temp);   // error is in this line
```

i think you want to make **TreeNode, int** as pair,

```
deque <pair<TreeNode, int> > q; // here is the different
```

then add to a deque，

```
q.push_back(temp);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your declaration of `q` is wrong.  Normally a `deque` will only require one template argument - the type to store in the deque.  The second parameter, if present, is an allocator type for the deque.

Answer (score 2):

According to [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/), the second template argument of deque should be an Alloc class.